# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller not working

Tags: kubernetes, dns, controller, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using minikube to have a local Kubernetes cluster.

I enabled the ingress addon with the following command :

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

I have created an application that turns actually in my cluster and also a service tied to it plus an ingress resource where **mydomain.name** will forward traffic to that service.

The issue that I have: this will not work if I don't add an entry like the following one to the **/etc/hosts** file :

```
<kubernetes_cluster_ip_adress> mydomain.name
```

I thought having the ingress controller with an ingress resource would do the DNS resolution & that I don't need to add any entry to the /etc/hosts file but maybe I am wrong.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you provide logs from the ingress controller?

Comment: Could you please share YAML files that you are using? How did you setup your minikube cluster - on Linux, Windows or Mac? Which [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) did you use?